# Connecting Laptop to LCD TV: 4 Pin S-Video + 3.5 mm Audio

Tags: laptop, tv-out

I am trying to connect laptop to Samsung LCD tv. I can transmit video with an S-Video->S-Video cable and it works fine. However there is no sound since the S-Video cable is 4 pins.

Then I try to transmit audio with an 3.5 mm audio cable. There is only PC input on the TV for 3.5 mm jack but it results no sound, since the source is selected as S-Video (not PC)

Do you have any suggestions? Only solution seems like to get a VGA cable and selecting PC for source for now, but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Well, i'd suggest a 3.5mm to RCA and a S-video -> composite adaptor

Comment: And how would that help @Journeyman Geek?

Comment: well, You'd have sound. I VERY vaguely recall using S-Video with 3.5 mm to RCA, but i neither have the TV, nor any laptops with s-video at this point of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VGA would result in the same (albeit with much better video quality than the S-Video) since VGA is again a video-only interface. What you are doing currently is right - however, you'll have to map the video input to the audio jack. Your TV's settings menu should have such an option. If you post the TV's specific make and model, we can take a look at the manual and get to a solution.

Another better alternative is if the Panel supports HDMI and your PC/laptop is equipped with HDMI use that, HDMI can be used for both HD audio and HD video simultaneously.

EDIT: Based on the provided model number

This is what your TVs connections should look like. The problem is the TV does not support assignable inputs. That means you now have following two options.

1. *(Recommended)* - Buy a VGA cable and connect it to the VGA port marked 'PC' in the following diagram. Connect your existing 3.5 - 3.5 stereo cable to to the jack marked as "Audio" under PC IN
2. Use your existing S-Video cable and connect it to the side panel "AV In". Buy a 3.5 -> RCA L R audio cable. Connect the 3.5 end to your laptop's audio out and the RCA L R ends to the jacks marked Audio L R right below the S Video and composite (Yellow) jacks on the side panel.

[image]

Comment: the side panel is exactly like the second image, and that's where i connect s video. the back is like this: http://www.televisions.com/tvs/samsung-televisions/samsung-lcd-tvs/Samsung-LE-46-A-656659/Design-Connectivity.php but there is no optical audio out and the hole with the arrow on my tv

Comment: Umm, would it hurt to mention the model number, if isn't much of a privacy concern?

Comment: no, of course no problem. LE32A431T2. sorry, did not know it would matter :) thanks

Comment: Thanks for the model number :). I've downloaded the manual and have updated the answer accordingly.